# Read values from a dictionary with multiple items for each key, Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With some help here in the forums I've made a script that sorts files and reads data from several Excelfiles, in addition to one that writes these data into a script. From sorting the exceldocuments the output looks like this:

```
   C:/eclipse/TST-folder\kop_tstdoc.xls
    C:/eclipse/TST-folder\tstdoc.xls
```

After that I read these data into a script that pulls out the cell-values I am interested in and writes these data into a dictionary called *"val_dict"*. This dict is built like this:

```
val_dict[filename] = [weightvalue, lenghtvalue, speedvalue]
```

The finished dict will consist of an increasing number of files and values, which has already passed 50 .xls-files. The output for the dict will look something like this:

```
{'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\kop_tstdoc.xls': [10.0, 21.0, 30.0],
    'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\tstdoc.xls': [3.0, 5.0, 5.0]}
```

I want to use for example the *"weightvalue"* in a function for scaling data to a fitting size for test-modeling. Below is the function *"scale_weight"* that is supposed to calculate a *x1* value as a scalingfactor, based on the *"weightvalue* from each document and an user defined *"inputweight"*. 
I am having problems reading the *weightvalue* from my dictionary, as I so far have ended up using the filename, the whole list and so on, instead of pulling the *weightvalue* from my dict. Can anyone give me tips, or maybe a different approach of how to do this? **Script for scaling below:**

```
 def scale_weight():        # Repeat for each value.
    for filename in val_dict:
        for x1 in range(len(val_dict)):
            values = val_dict.get(weightvalue)  #want "weightvalue" from dict here
            x1 = eval(inputweight) / eval(values)
    return x1

for x1 in scale_weight():
    print x1
```

What I want with this script is to return an *x1* value for each filename in my dictionary, where the *x1* value is equal to the userdefined *inputweight* divided with the *weightvalue* from each Excel-file.

**UPDATE**

```
val_dict output looks like this:
{'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\kop_tstdoc.xls': [10.0, 21.0, 30.0],
    'C:/eclipse/TST-folder\\tstdoc.xls': [3.0, 5.0, 5.0]}
```

Modified script:

```
inputweight = int(raw_input('Insert weight'))       

def scale_weight():
    for filename in val_dict:
        values = val_dict.get(filename)[0]
        x1 = float(inputweight) / float(int(values))
    return x1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val_dict.get(weightvalue)` gets the **value** from the inputted key (in this case, you are trying to get the value of the key weightvalue). There is no `weightvalue` key, so this returns `None`.

What you probably want is `val_dict.get(filename)[0]` which returns the first element in the value of the filename.

There's also no reason for you to use `eval()`. Use `int()` to convert a string to an integer.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Is there a way to define `weightvalue` for each `weightvalue`-item from the dict then?

Comment: @Havard `val_dict.get(filename)[0]` -- Does this help?

Comment: Yes!  It helped a lot! Thanks:) 
Would you be able to help me localize this last error as well?  I realize now that I need to read up a bit on integers and dictionaries :)

Comment: @Havard Well if you're going to only return one value, then there is no need for a loop at the end of your code

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you see a reason to why I only get one x1 value as result? When I try to print the outcome I only get the value from the second dictionary. Been trying to fix this for a while now, so would very much appreciate any hints:)

Comment: @Havard Because every time you loop through your for-loop, you keep on overriding the value of the variable `x1`. Perhaps append it to a list outside of the loop